# Unusual output of file

Tags: c, file, io

This is my code for reading a file:

```
void readNote() {
    FILE* file = fopen("records.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        int i = 0;
        while(line[i] != ' ') {
            printf("%c", line[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

And this is my file:

```
December 20: Note 1



March 21: Note 2



March 4: My note 1



June 23: Note 2 happy



January 3: Birthday



January 3: Birthday
```

And this is the output when I run my function:

```
#     @Γ⌂è∙  ≈áA     [3wè∙
#     @Γ⌂è∙  ≈áA     [3wè∙
#     @Γ⌂è∙  ≈áA     [3wè∙  December
cember
cember
cemberMarch
rch
rch
rchMarch
rch
rch
rchJune
ne
ne
neJanuary
nuary
nuary
nuaryJanuary
```

Why are those unusual characters popping out?

Comment: Check your encoding settings.

Comment: Firstly, which encoding do you use in your text file?

Comment: note that your while loop will run over the end of the string into undefined memory if it doesn't encounter a space. that is also the reason for the truncated month names (the empty lines just overwrite the first two chars, the rest stays the same from the previous loop)

Comment: Things can occasionally be hard to see, especially when new-lines and spaces are involved. Here, I have changed your code just slightly, made it print characters as numbers (as in, their numeric values) and spaced/aligned them nicely: http://ideone.com/NrMayh It is exactly like speising described, just visualized. You can see lines starting with `10  0` which is a new-line and a terminating zero that `fgets` got and appended from/to your empty lines. They are followed by the remnants of the previous lines every time. They end exactly where the previous line ended, due to your `!= ' '`.

Comment: @speising Agree about the loop.  Also bet the first line of OP's file is not "December 20: Note 1", but something like "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

change

```
while(line[i] != ' ') {
```

to

```
while(line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\0') {
```

Comment: The code: line[i] != '\n' is expecting '\n' to be a single char.  That is not true in windows/dos.  So your code will fail under those OSs.  Much better to check for the return value of the call to fgets() and use that value as a length limiter, along with the ' ' and '\0' checks.  Also, for safety, always reset the input variable 'line' to nulls before each read to avoid looking at obsolete/trash data.

Comment: @user3629249 it will be converted to '\n' from (CR+LF) in text mode under windows system.